# What is the correct nomenclature for timezones?

Tags: datetime, timezone

There are different ways of identifying the same timezone, which can each be used by different programs in different ways. I live in Wisconsin, so we generally refer to the timezone here as "Central Time." But I know that Windows has a registry entry for `Central Standard Time`, which in fact is actually comprised of both Central Standard Time (CST) and Central Daylight Time (CDT). But more recently I've seen this timezone displayed as `America/Chicago`.

What are the right terms to refer to these two different standards? So for instance, what do you call the `America/Chicago` way of identifying the timezone? Is that something like the "Standard TZ Info name" or the "ISO-1234567 timezone name" or the "Eggert TZ name"?

And what about the slightly more familiar `Central Standard Time`? Do you refer to that syntax as the "Friendly timezone name", or the "ISO-987654321 timezone name", or something like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no exact standards for the nomenclature, but here are some guidelines:

- Time zones like `America/Chicago` are commonly referred to as "Olson Time Zones", "IANA Time Zones", or "TZ Database Time Zones".  There is some background [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) with the history of the database that explains some of this.

  - "IANA Time Zones" is probably the most correct form these days, as the project now resides under the stewardship of [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).
  - Occasionally, you'll hear them referred to by the language that uses them, as in "PHP Time Zones" or "Java Time Zones".  This usually comes from a lack of understanding about the implementation, and I would discourage using these names.
- The time zones in the Windows registry are commonly known as "Microsoft Time Zones" or "Windows Time Zones".

  - I'd actually encourage calling them "Legacy Windows Time Zones", as IANA time zones are slowly making their way into Windows, such as with the WinRT classes: [`Windows.Globalization.Calendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn264115.aspx) and [`Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn264145.aspx).
  - I sometimes hear them called ".NET Time Zones", or "TimeZoneInfo Time Zones", based on their usage within the .NET Framework, but I would discourage this sort of naming.
  - Pay no attention to the naming conventions of the Windows time zone identifiers.  They are all over the place.

Some of this is also covered in [the 'timezone' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Oh, and since we're talking about naming, it's "time zone" (two words), not "timezone".  :)

Answer (score 1):

Time zones (such as "Pacific Time" or "France Time") can be formatted in different ways:

- **"metazone"** names, such as "Pacific Time" or "Pacific Standard Time", that can apply to segments of a country or groups of countries.
- **location** (country or city) based names, such as "Paris Time" or "Japan Standard Time"
  These are constructed using patterns (see below), plus Country/Region Names and City Names.
  When a "metazone" name is absent, a location based name is used as a fallback.
- **raw offsets**, like "GMT+10:00"
  These are constructed using patterns (see below).

For each of the first two, there are three choices:

- Winter (standard) time, such as "Atlantic Standard Time"
- Summer (daylight) time, such as "Atlantic Daylight Time"
- Generic time, such as "Atlantic Time". This is used for recurring times (such as in a Calendar program) that change between summer and winter.

[image]

Comment: This is good information, and these are valid terms within the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) project, but I'm not sure this is what the OP was looking for.